# Jquery Custom image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a little complex code (Coz i am not an expert) to mage a gallery.. But i want to do it more simple.. Bellow is my code:

This is the buttons:

```
<div class="pic1">Image1</div>
<div class="pic2">Image2</div>
<div class="pic3">Image3</div>
```

This is the each image:

```
<div class="PicsHolder">

<div id="pic1" style="padding: 2px; margin: auto;">
<img src="image_gallery/1.jpg" alt="" width="100%" />
<div style="width:610px; padding-bottom:4px; margin-top:10px; float:left; color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
Some text in Here!!!
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="pic2" style="padding: 2px; margin: auto; display: none;">
<img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="image_gallery/2.jpg" alt="" width="100%" border="0" />
<div style="width:610px; padding-bottom:4px; margin-top:10px; float:left; color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
Some text in Here Image 2!!!
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>


<div id="pic3" style="padding: 2px; margin: auto; display: none;">
<img style="margin: 0 auto;" src="image_gallery/3.jpg" alt="" width="100%" border="0" />
<div style="width:610px; padding-bottom:4px; margin-top:10px; float:left; color:#000; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
Some text in Here Image 3!!!
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

And my JAvascript (and the complicated part)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
            var myString = window.location.href;
            var finals = myString[myString.length - 1];
            if (finals == "") {
                $("#pic2").hide();
                $("#pic3").hide();
                $("#pic1").fadeIn("fast");
            }
            if (finals == "1") {
                $("#pic2").hide();
                $("#pic3").hide();
                $("#pic1").fadeIn("fast");
            }
            if (finals == "2") {
                $("#pic1").hide();
                $("#pic3").hide();
                $("#pic2").fadeIn("fast");
            }
            if (finals == "3") {
                $("#pic1").hide();
                $("#pic2").hide();
                $("#pic3").fadeIn("fast");
            }
});
</script)



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
            var currentURL = window.location.href;
            var p1 = "?id=1";
            var p2 = "?id=2";
            var p3 = "?id=3";

            var p1url = window.location.href + p1;
            var p2url = window.location.href + p2;
            var p3url = window.location.href + p3;

            $(".pic1").click(function() {
                $("#pic2").hide();
                $("#pic3").hide();
                $("#pic4").hide();
                window.location.href = p1url;
                $("#pic1").fadeIn("fast");
            });
            $(".pic2").click(function() {
                $("#pic1").hide();
                $("#pic3").hide();
                window.location.href = p2url;
                $("#pic2").fadeIn("fast");
            });
            $(".pic3").click(function() {
                $("#pic1").hide();
                $("#pic2").hide();
                window.location.href = p3url;
                $("#pic3").fadeIn("fast");
            });
});
</script>
```

1. Is there any possibility to do all this jquery code more simple?
2. is there any possibility to make it more dynamic? I mean if i want to add more images 
   like this way:

   Some text in Here Image 2!!!

The jquery code that i am using to calculate the images and generate the rest code?

Regards!

Comment: For a start you could look at using loops to make the number of images supported more dynamic. You could also revisit your html and use `ul > li` as containers for each of your slides to simplify your markup

Comment: I have to say that you are reinventing the wheel to an extent. There are loads of jquery plugins that will do what you want. e.g. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/